# Reading XML only contents from a Log file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a log file which stores the data in XML format. I want to read this data but the problem that I am getting is that log file is not well structured XML file. It contains some additional data like :

```
03/22/2013 : 13:23:32 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element1>
...
...
...
</element1>
```

As you will notice 03/22/2013 : 13:23:32 is not allowing me to read data and throwing exception saying "Data at the root level is invalid"

I am using following method to read XML

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("file.log");
            string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
            label1.Text = xmlcontents;
```

Please guide me through the solution as this is a rare case for me. I tried googling for a solution but couldnt succeed
Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can make it recognize as xml. Maybe you need to try to change its extension to .txt temporarily and just parse it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack would be to parse the log file to extract only the text found between the root xml tags, in your case, what is found between < element1> and < /element1>.

You can search for the tag < ?xml, and what comes after ?> is your root tag, and go with that. Depending on how predictable of clearly structured the log file is, you can formulate better ways of doing this, but if nothing else works, you can try this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(string.Concat(File.ReadAllLines("file.log").Skip(1)));
```

Reorganize your XML, so the date become an Element or Attribute, if the file is too large

Answer (score 0):

You can skip first line

```
var onlyXml = (File.ReadAllLines("file.log")).Skip(1).SelectMany(l => l).ToArray();
var xmlContent = new String(onlyXml);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
label1.Text = xmlcontents;
```

EDIT

You can get only xml between first '<' and last '>'

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("file.log");
var beginIndex = text.IndexOf('<');
var endIndex = text.LastIndexOf('>');
var onlyXml = text.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex + 1);
```

Comment: To convert Enumerable<String> to one Enumerable<Char>

Comment: Structure of file is such that I can't skip line 1. Moreover I have multiple such entries in the file. please see the Edit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read whole file to array of lines (`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string path)`) and then join elements of array skipping first line and rest of lines which is not fragments of XML structure (assuming your sample is only part of input file).